# How do I pivot selected group column values into row values in a sorted order

Tags: excel, google-sheets, pivot, pivot-table, data-visualization

I've the below sample data with me

`Place     Name     Time of Travel`
`Paris     Mark     2015-04-21 03:00:00`
`Seoul     Mark     2014-11-24 15:32:00`
`HongKong  Dave     2016-01-22 10:32:00`
`Rome      Dave     2016-11-29 17:39:19`
`Mumbai    Dave     2014-05-22 14:30:11`
`Seoul     Dave     2017-02-11 19:10:11`

I am looking for a report with the below data

`Name   Place1   Place2    Place3    Place4`
`Mark   Seoul    Paris`
`Dave   Mumbai   HongKong    Rome    Seoul`

The column values have been sorted using time in an ascending order, I tried solving this with pivots, however I couldn't get my head around it. Can we get a desired result like the above using Google Spreadsheets/Excel or I'd have to write a Google Script/Macros to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would go about it:

1. Add a column to identify that Paris is the first trip for Mark, Seoul his second, and so on. Use the formula that I wrote for the first cell and drag it down. You can hide this column if you wish to.

[Count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZO4dr.png)

2. In your report, you are going to lookup in the initial table Mark's first trip, his second, and so on. Copy the formula for Mark's first place, and drag it right.

[Index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1S1i.png)

This formula looks up "Mark x" where x corresponds to the first, second, etc. trip of Mark [MATCH], and uses [INDEX] to get the cell to the left of it defining the destination. Drag the formula to the right.

Copy the formula for Dave, but make sure that you change $H$12 to $H$13 to lookup "Dave x" and not "Mark x".

If the formula is used often, you can remove the #N/A by putting all the formula in an [IFERROR] formula, but I didn't want to overcomplicate.

Let me know if that works!

Gabriel

Comment: Thanks for the answer Gabriel, the approach does work, however I have a large dataset I've to apply this solution to. There can be innumerous `Places` and innumerous combinations of `Places` so can't have a generalised formulae to get the order.